# alpha and beta channels android console

Tags: android, google-play, android-testing

I don't find information about this new functions in the android console. Exists any special name for the package name? I need to change this name every time I need to pass througth the channels, With gradle is very easy but in eclipse with the traditional compiler is hard. can I have the same package name for the beta and alpha release? thinking to have once app at time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a user will subscribe to an alpha or beta channel and when they download the app from the market, the market is smart enough to determine which version of your app to serve up.